# Substract two database entries based on value of a certain field

Tags: mysql, aggregate

Good evening everyone,

I am looking for the most elegant way to substract two values of one column based on the value in another column. Until now I could only find hacky and unreadable solutions:

I have a table containing entries when orders on an exchange were opened and closed. It looks like this:

```
|| DATETIME || ORDERID || ACTION || TYPE || PRICE || ...
  2018-01-01   a34hsbf    OPEN      LONG    0.23
  2018-01-02   ghs7fa0    OPEN      SHORT   0.45
  2018-01-03   a34hsbf    CLOSE     LONG    0.47
  ...
```

Now I want to return a new table containing the differences between entries with the same ORDERID. There can always only be two entries with the same ORDERID. The new table should be indexed by the greater DATETIME of those two entries. Also the difference should take into account if the TYPE was LONG or SHORT. E.g. for LONG a rising price must give a positive difference, for SHORT it must give a negative difference and vice versa.

The new table should look like the following:

```
|| DATETIME || ORDERID || TYPE || DIFF ||
  2018-01-03   a34hsbf    LONG    0.24
  ...
```

Many thanks in advance for your help. :)

Comment: Do you have a *working* "hacky" or "unreadable" solution? If so, include that. What's "elegant" to one person could be hacky or unreadable to another. Also, could you ever have an "open" listed as a "long" and a "close" listed as a "short", or vice versa? Logically you shouldn't, but I don't know if your DB/app enforces that logic in some way.

Comment: No, unfortunately I haven't saved them since none was to my liking. But you are right, beauty is a subjective topic. However, McNets solution below is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As RDFozz has pointed out in his comments, this solution only works if:

- There is one OPEN and one CLOSE entries
- Both entries has the same type, 'LONG' or 'SHORT'

> ```
> select case when t1.datetime > t2.datetime 
>             then t1.datetime 
>             else t2.datetime end as datetime,
>        t1.orderid,
>        t1.type,
>        case when t1.type = 'SHORT' 
>             then t1.price - t2.price 
>             else t2.price - t1.price end as diff
> from   tbl t1
> join   tbl t2
> on     t1.orderid = t2.orderid
> and    t1.type = t2.type
> and    t2.action = 'CLOSE'
> where  t1.action = 'OPEN'
> ```
>
> ```
> datetime   | orderid | type | diff
> :--------- | :------ | :--- | ---:
> 2018-01-03 | a34hsbf | LONG | 0.24
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=2b6185dbf4184cc442374a2dca6b8970)*

Comment: Thank you McNets, that is really beautiful, exactly what I was looking for. Unfortunately, I can't give you an upvote due to my reputation but that is the best solution I have seen so far. ;)

Comment: You should be able to accept his answer, in any case, on your own question.

Comment: Ah, yes, you are right, did that. :)

Comment: You could add `AND t1.type = t2.type AND t1.type IN ('SHORT', 'LONG')`, either in `ON` or `WHERE` condition, to avoid returning results from possible bogus data.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ maybe it could be better add: `t1.type = t2.type` in `ON` condition?

Comment: Same thing. ON or WHERE, doesn't matter for performance. For clarity, yes, I'd use ON.

Comment: One more thing, isn't the case statement unneccessary for the datetime since we require the t1.action always to be "open" in the where clause at the end?

Comment: @Nimrare yes, you could avoid it.